# Form submission canceled because the form is not connected на внешнем сервере

Tags: javascript, form

Суть проблемы в том, что имеется две копии проекта. Локальная и продакшн. В локальной эта форма всё успешно отправляет и информация обрабатывается, на продакшне выдает ошибку о том что форма не подключена.
Объявление формы

```js
function addDeleteForms() {
    $('[data-method]').append(function () {
        if (! $(this).find('form').length > 0) {
            return "\n" +
                "<div class='frm' data-action='" + $(this).attr('href') + "' data-name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "' style='display:none'" +
                " data-method='" + $(this).attr('data-method') + "' data-token='" + $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') + "'></div>\n";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    })
        .removeAttr('href')
        .attr('style', 'cursor:pointer;')
        .attr('onclick', 'submitFRM($(this).find(".frm"));');
        //.attr('onclick', '$(this).find("form").send()');
}
```

Вызов обработчика

```js
 addDeleteForms();

    /**
     * Generic confirm form delete using Sweet Alert
     */
    $(document).on('submit', 'form[name=delete_perm],form[name=delete_item]', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        /*title: "Warning",
            text: "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
            type: "warning",
         confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",*/
        if($(form).attr('name')=='delete_perm' || $(form).attr('name')=='delete_item'){
            swal({
                title: "Предупреждение",
                text: "Вы уверены, что хотите удалить этот элемент?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Да, удалить его!",
                cancelButtonText: "Отменить",
                closeOnConfirm: true
            }, function(confirmed) {
                if (confirmed)
                    form.submit();
            });
        }else{
            form.submit();
        }

    });
```

Ну и собственно добавление этих самых кнопок в табличку в которой отображается информация.

```js
$('body').delegate('#<?=$grid->getConfig()->getName()?> .pagination a','click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent_form=$(this).parents('form'),
            key=parent_form.find('div.keys'),
            url=$(this).attr('href'),
            param=parent_form.serializeArray();
        $.each(param,function(i,val){
            var myRe = /<?=$grid->getConfig()->getName()?>\[page\]/ig;
            var myArray = myRe.exec(val['name']);
            if(myArray){
                delete param[i]
            }
        })
        var  gets=$.param(param);
        url=url+'&'+gets;
        key.prop('title',url);
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('<?=$grid->getConfig()->getName()?>');
        setTimeout( function(){
            addDeleteForms()
        },2000);
    });
```

Господа, в какую сторону копать? Я уже как только мог так и сравнивал коды страниц - идентично за исключением адреса обращения ( что логично ). Почему один и тот же код на локальном сервере отрабатывает, а на внешнем выдает "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"?

Comment: Возможно это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053775/getting-error-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected

Comment: Действительно только в хроме возникает это затруднение. Но как в моем случае добавить ajax форму в DOM?